# How to unlink iPhone 5s from former staff member's Apple ID?

Tags: icloud, iphone, accounts

Former staff member left iPhone 5s which is linked to his Apple ID. Sign in to iCloud pops up all the time.  Find My Phone feature was on. I've asked him to remove this phone from Find My Phone which he did. Here is instructions how he did it https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702?locale=en_US

Now, although he removed iphone from his iCloud account, the phone still asks to sign in to his iCloud. I cannot reset it, erase the data and anything else.

So the question is does removing iPhone from "Find my Phone" remotely (online) logs off from iCloud?
How can I sign of from his iCloud and reset the phone? Erase it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to use the 'turn off find my phone' after former staff member turned it off via iCloud.com ?

Comment: Yes I did, but it still asks for Apple ID password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way to test is plug the phone into iTunes and restore it. The computer will retrieve lock status and let you know if the server side lock is present or reset.

You could also tap to the settings app on the iPhone and reset, erase all content and settings. That will need a wifi or cellular connection to verify the same server side lock status.

The article you [linked has three very different scenarios](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702?locale=en_US) - depending on which was employed, you might still not be done with that user. It might be important to have them send a remote erase or you perform the erase before they do the unlock part with their ID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restoring the phone using recovery mode?
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

That should update the settings when it try and reactivate that its been removed from the former apple id.